# How to rename the column names - JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to rename the column names inside a database just by changing the entity in Spring Frameworks JPA Hibernate?

Assume that I have created the table`MyDatabase` and its columns. But I want to change these without erase the rows inside the table. How can I do that?

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class MyDatabase{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String Ordernummer;
    private String VentilNamn;
    private String SerieNummer;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with `@Column`.

For example:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

    // id etc

    @Column(name = "my_column_name")
    private String column;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But Hibernate cannot alter the column name.